# Mounting NFS on AIX so that files are not owned by nobody:nobody

Tags: permissions, users, nfs, aix, group

How can I mount an NFS share on AIX? The share was created on a Windows server 2012, I created the NFS role as a server and client as well. I set the properties on the Windows server to share the folder correctly.

I used this command:

```
mount -v nfs -o rw,vers=3,wsize=256 192.168.3.222:/Compartido /Compartido
```

The thing is, the NFS mounts successfully but, on the AIX system, when I type the `ls` command, it shows me that all of the files are owned by user `nobody` and group `nobody`. I want to know how can I set or manipulate all files, folders on its NFS.

I have to use NFS, not CIFS. I am working on AIX 7.1.

Comment: probably an artifact of the Windows NFS server presenting the userid & group ID of those files as a number that doesn't match up to a uid or gid on the AIX side. Can you force the Windows NFS server side to present the files as a valid user/group?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I have in the past used `mkpasswd` in a cygwin environment to dump all the  domain accounts into a `/etc/passwd` style file, this then allows unix systems to recognize Microsoft domain users and groups for nfs and sshd without changing the windows side of things. Not sure if its applicable for this situation , but a possible suggestion.

Comment: I have the default values on windows server. -- Enable unmapped user access (by UID/GID).

Comment: I did not resolve my issue yet. Any update?.

Comment: An any update ?